# tcpdump can't capture traffic from windows to WSL2

Tags: wsl-2, tcpdump

I'm using tcpdump to troubleshoot a network issue during my development work.

In my development, I run a simple HTTP server on port 8081 in WSL2. And use Postman in Windows to send request to the server with the url: http://localhost:8081. It works well.

Then I want to capture the network packets for this request by running tcpdump in WSL2:

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -n host localhost
```

But no packets are captured. I confirmed tcpdump itself can work by doing other tests (if both the client and server are in WSL2 system, the traffic can be captured very well).

So how to make it work? I know I can move the server to Windows and use Wireshark to monitor the network. But in the technical level, I want to know how it works.